# NSDate() vs NSDate.date() in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa, nsdate

I´m following along with the [Bloc.io Swiftris tutorial](https://www.bloc.io/tutorials/swiftris-build-your-first-ios-game-with-swift#!/chapters/680) where they initialize a date by:

```
lastTick = NSDate.date()
```

Which causes a compile error:

```
'date()' is unavailable: use object construction 'NSDate()'
```

Which should equal:

```
NSDate *lastTick = [NSDate date];
```

(from the [NSDate reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDate/date))

Did Apple change the [Swift interface to NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html), since I have seen other examples that use `NSDate.date`?

Is this just NSDate or can you not call type methods for any Objective-C APIs?

Comment: In Objective-C, `[NSDate date]` simply calls `[[NSDate alloc] init]`. Hence, you do not need to call `NSDate.date()` in Swift. Simply calling `NSDate()` will initialise a date object with the current date.

Comment: @ZeMoon Why did you delete your answer? I was about to accept it.

Comment: Well, I thought it applied more as a comment, but apparently it was sufficient as the answer... Have undeleted it, you can vote it up at least, if not accept it... :D

Comment: do you mistaken NSDate.date() instead of NSDate.init() ?

Comment: No, I was following a tutorial which used .date. It says so very clearly in the question.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`[NSDate date]` is a factory method for constructing an NSDate object.

If you read the guide "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C", there is a section on interacting with Objective-C apis:

> For consistency and simplicity, Objective-C factory methods get mapped as convenience initializers in Swift. This mapping allows them to be used with the same concise, clear syntax as initializers.”
>
> Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C.” iBooks. https://itun.es/gb/1u3-0.l

So the factory method:

```
[NSDate date]
```

is converted into an initializer in Swift

```
NSDate()
```

It's not just NSDate where you will find this pattern, but in other Cocoa API's with factory methods.

Comment: No doubt Apple wouldn't supply `[NSDate data]` in Objective-C either if the class were implemented from new now; ARC means that there's limited extra convenience in simple `alloc] init] autorelease];`-style factory methods.

Answer (score 12):

It seems that `NSDate()` is new syntax. Previously, `NSDate.date()` worked,

but **now you should use** **`NSDate()`**

Comment: Actually `NSDate.date()` gives me a compiler error.

Comment: Yes, old syntax no more supported

Comment: @ChikabuZ your bad phrasing is misleading. If you meant that "previously, `NSDate.date()` worked", then don't write "earlier `NSDate.date()` works", because they mean completely different things.

Comment: This does answer my question either, I already knew that I should use `NSDate()` from the error message in my question (I´m not an idiot). My question was about why the Swift interface is different from Obj.-C

Comment: I think that Apple decide to change syntax to more intuitive and short. [NSDate date] and NSDate() looks good, but NSDate.date() is worse.

Answer (score 8):

In Objective-C, `[NSDate date]` simply calls `[[NSDate alloc] init]`. Hence, you do not need to call `NSDate.date()` in Swift. Simply calling `NSDate()` will initialise a date object with the current date.

Answer (score 6):

> Did Apple change the Swift interface to `NSDate`?

Yes, they did. For me, the compiler tells:

> Foundation.NSDate:3:26: note: 'date()' has been explicitly marked unavailable here:
>
> `@objc(date) class func date() -> Self!`

So it is explicitly marked unavailable to Swift. This means that it has officially been deprecated.

Comment: Is there some setting in Xcode to get depreciation messages like this?

Comment: @papirtiger sorry, I don't get what you are referring to -- compiler errors are displayed in Xcode by default (as far as I know anyway... I don't use Xcode.)

Comment: I only get `'date()' is unavailable: use object construction 'NSDate()'` in Xcode. What compiler do you use?

Comment: @papirtiger I use the very same Swift compiler that is bundled with Xcode (since there are no other compilers for Swift). I run it using `xcrun swift`.

Comment: Perhaps you're not using the same version of Xcode. Apple changed this in 6.1.